# Trouble positioning bootstrap/ CSS element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new at coding and have a problem. I'm working on a project and it has to be done mostly in Bootstrap, although I added some css. I want it to look like:

informational bullets down left IMAGE in center, Informational bullets on right. So bullets, image, bullets.

I believe I have the left side ok and the image is perfectly centered where I want it to be, but the right side is NOT cooperating at all. No matter what I've tried, it keeps remaining at the bottom right of the image instead of starting at top of image on the right hand side.

I've tried using p tag then enclosed it in a div, then got rid of p tag and only used a div. I've tried styling it all kinds of ways.... display: inline-block, position:center, I tried messing with the margins, I tried using bootstraps' text-center in the opening tags, I've tirelessly searched YouTube. I don't know how to make this look the way I want it to look. Again, an image centered and bulleted text going down each side of image.

```css
    .bottom {
      
    }
    img {
      border: 20px inset gray;
      width: 500px;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .bullet  {
       
    }
    .bullet2 {
      display:inline-block;
      margin-left: 850px;
      margin-bottom:-300px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container bg-primary">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

        <h1 class="text-center text-white">Water</h1>
          <h2 class="text-center text-white"><em>Where there is no water, there is no life</em></h2>

        </div><!--end col12-->

      </div><!--end row-->

      <div class="body">
        <div class="bullet text-white">This is a cool and informative paragraph</div>
                    
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d6/69/fd/d669fd1ff1deecff0644292b02fe5a7d--charity-water-water-sources.jpg" alt="boy happy with water"/>
        
        <div class="bullet2 text-white">This is a cool and informative paragraph</div>
          
         </div><!--body-->
      </div><!--end container-->
```

Comment: Your question is far from clear. Do you want to display content in 3 columns, with left and right columns having bulleted text and the middle one an image? How do you want them vertically aligned? I suggest using a picture to draw the outcome, since your web vocabulary seems limited.

Comment: in Bootstrap 4 use img-fluid, not img-reponsive

Comment: Hey to all who took the time to respond. Yes my design/developer lingo is a work in progress lol. For those who got what I was trying to say, thank you! I'll work with all of your suggestions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap.

If I understood correctly, this markup schema should do it:

```
container
  row
    col-sm-4
      bullets
    col-sm-4
      img-responsive
    col-sm-4
      bullets
```

Depending on version of Bootstrap and where you want this to break (responsive-wise), you might have to change `col-sm-4` to other Bootstrap grid classes.
Documentation: [v3](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid). [v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).

And a working example, using v3.3.7:

```css
/* you don't actually need this CSS, it's just for SO */
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul>
        <li>A bullet</li>
        <li>Another bullet</li>
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/d6/69/fd/d669fd1ff1deecff0644292b02fe5a7d--charity-water-water-sources.jpg" alt="boy happy with water" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul>
        <li>A bullet</li>
        <li>Another bullet</li>
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I know my question wasnt the clearest. But I will work with your suggestions. Thank you very much!